# Management communication while monopolies and mergers commission decision pending?

Tags: management, united-kingdom, layoff, acquisition

My company has been bought by a company who recently bought our largest competitor also.

The acquisition has been sent to the UK Monopolies and mergers commission. So they need the OK from them before the merger itself can proceed. We've heard **practically nothing** apart from a brief email from the MD saying it was happening, I think this was only sent because the people buying the company had spoken to the press.

Is the outcome of the commission preventing the management from talking to us or are they simply not communicating?

What are the rules around merging companies and what can and can't be said to who? Specifically the workforce.

Comment: Not hearing much until the details are settled is completely typical and should be expected. They'll tell you when they have reached agreement.

Comment: My question is, is there any **legal reason** why they can't say anything? Or have they taken a decision not to.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no legal reason. But as @Myles points out, there are plenty of other reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be pretty normal.  I don't know the local rules regarding this but the logic behind not sharing info is sound.  This process can have major details change pretty rapidly and it wouldn't be fair for employees to make life decisions around information until it is 100% decided.  Also leaked details can drastically effect share prices (imagine insider info that the merger hit a snag and may not go through) which in turn feed back into the merger process.

Comment: To add: The rules on insider trading might also tie the hands of management quite a bit. To the extent that they can't reveal any information to the employees that is not also available to the shareholders/general public.